# Using ASP.NET Blazor, how do I make Bootstrap navbar collapse when menu item is clicked?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, blazor

On mobile, I open the responsive menu and click on a menu item `<NavLink>`. I am routed to the new page, but the menu stays open and does not automatically collapse. When I click the `<NavLink>` a second time, the menu collapses. How do I make it auto collapse after clicking on `<NavLink>` the first time?

I'm using some of the code from the default Blazor template that looks like it would solve this problem, but it does not.

The `navbar-collapse div` when menu is **opened by button**:
`

```
<div class="navbar-collapse justify-content-end collapse show" id="navbarNav" b-8i8utxilae="" style="">
```

The `navbar-collapse div` when  **clicked once**:

```
<div class=" navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav" b-8i8utxilae="" style="">
```

The `navbar-collapse div` when  **clicked twice**:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav" b-8i8utxilae="" style="">
```

Here is all of the code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="d-inline-block" style="width: 50px;">
        <a class="navbar-brand fw-bold" href="/">
            <img class="w-100 me-3 my-2" src="/images/Magnolia_white.png" alt="no image" />
            <span class="no-mobile">Magnolia</span>
        </a>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler bg-secondary px-1" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="oi oi-menu text-light m-1"></span>
        </button>
        <div onclick="@ToggleNavMenu" class="@NavMenuCssClass navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item ms-2">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link fw-bold" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                        Home
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

```
@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }
}
```

Comment: `onclick="@ToggleNavMenu"` should be `@onclick="@ToggleNavMenu"`

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos Thank you! However, it unfortunately did not solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Javascript function to call the Bootstrap collapse method. Keeps the menu animation.

In your Blazor component put the following.

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <NavLink href="/Calendar" @onclick="CollapseMenu" class="nav-link">
        Calendar
    </NavLink>
</li>

async void CollapseMenu() => await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("myApp.collapseMenu");
```

In your Javascript file put the following.

```
myApp.collapseMenu = function () {
    let navbar = document.getElementById("myNavbar");

    if (navbar != null) {
        bootstrap.Collapse.getInstance(navbar).hide();
    }
};
```

Documentation found here, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/collapse/#usage

The Bootstrap documentation provides the following example. However, this code will collapse every element with the class .collapse on the page. I had other collapsible elements on the page which I did not want to collapse and came up with the solution above.

```
const collapseElementList = document.querySelectorAll('.collapse')
const collapseList = [...collapseElementList].map(collapseEl => new bootstrap.Collapse(collapseEl))
```

Comment: This works. Thanks! Just to add more value: I had forgotten to add the `data-bs-toggle="collapse"` and `data-bs-target="myNavbar"` to my button that toggles the collapse. These attributes are important because they are how Bootstrap knows to initialize the collapsible element as a Collapse object. Without the attributes, or without initializing the collapsible via JS, `bootstrap.Collapse.getInstance(navbar).hide()` will not work.

Answer (score 2):

At your toggle button you should replace `data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"` with `@onclick="ToggleNavMenu"`. Which means that instead of letting Bootstrap toggle the navigation menu with JavaScript, you should do it manually from the Blazor component, so that the `collapseNavMenu` bool variable is always in sync with the state of the navigation menu.

```html
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggler bg-secondary px-1" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <span class="oi oi-menu text-light m-1"></span>
</button>
<div @onclick="ToggleNavMenu" class="@NavMenuCssClass navbar-collapse justify-content-end">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item ms-2">
            <NavLink class="nav-link fw-bold" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                Home
            </NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. However, it does not maintain the slide down animation that bootstrap provides.